Julia: splitting a substring only allows to pick the first entry of the output
I'm starting to learn Julia, and I have found a weird behaviour for the split() function that I don't know how to get around.
I'm writing a script to reformat the output of a PCA, and the first column, which contains the ID, has several fields compressed into it (Continent, Breed and Id number).
So the first step of the script is to iterate over this column of the DataFrame, split each entry twice and save each bit on the corresponding vector to add them to the dataframe as a new column later.
The issue is that when I try to do so the first split works fine, but the second one only lets me access the first entry (breed[1]), but if I try to get the second one (breed[2]) it fails with message

ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Vector{SubString{String}} at index [2]

However, when I print the output of that split it has 2 items inside SubString{String}["Wild", "Urial"].
The loop looks like this:
for i in ids
   newbreed, newid= split(i,":")
   pop, breed= split(newbreed,"-")
   append!(newids,newid)
   append!(newbreeds,breed)
   append!(newpops,pop)
end

And an example data can be:
Europe-Suffolk:Suff123
Asia-Altai:ALY453
Africa-Mbororo:123512

Any idea of what is causing this issue?

Are you sure that the type of breed in your code above is a Vector{SubString{String}}? The result of that split operation should make it just a SubString{String}, unless there are other types of values in ids that have multiple '-' characters.

The problem lies in using append! since the SubString{String} in this case has elements of Char, e.g.
one = []
two = []

for i in ids
  one, two = split(i, ":")
end

Looking at e.g. two
collect(two)
6-element Vector{Char}:
 '1': ASCII/Unicode U+0031 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
 '2': ASCII/Unicode U+0032 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
 '3': ASCII/Unicode U+0033 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
 '5': ASCII/Unicode U+0035 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
 '1': ASCII/Unicode U+0031 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
 '2': ASCII/Unicode U+0032 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)

append! tries to add each element.
From help?> append!

... add the elements of each collections to the end of it.

which in this case is a single character.
One solution is to use push!, from help?> push!

Insert one or more items in collection.

will add the whole collection of Chars, e.g.
newids = Vector{String}()
newbreeds = Vector{String}()
newpops = Vector{String}()

for i in ids
  newbreed, newid = split(i, ":")
  pop, breed = split(newbreed, "-")
  push!(newids, newid)
  push!(newbreeds, breed)
  push!(newpops, pop)
end

newids
3-element Vector{String}:
 "Suff123"
 "ALY453"
 "123512"

Another solution might be to store the data in a Matrix, then using a DataFrame to store it, e.g.
using DataFrames

dat = hcat([push!(string.(split(i[1], "-")), i[2]) for i in split.(ids, ":")]...)

DataFrame(eachrow(dat), ["pop", "breed", "id"])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ pop     breed    id      
     │ String  String   String  
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ Europe  Suffolk  Suff123
   2 │ Asia    Altai    ALY453
   3 │ Africa  Mbororo  123512

Data
ids = ["Europe-Suffolk:Suff123",
       "Asia-Altai:ALY453",
       "Africa-Mbororo:123512"]


The assigned value to breed is a scalar, not a Vector, so there is no second element to access (sort of: more about that at the end of the answer).
When you write the following, you are using Julia's destructuring assignment feature:
i = "AA-BB:CC"
x, y = split(i, ":")

When a comma-separated list of variables is on the left-hand side of an assignment operation like this, Julia assigns the first value of whatever iterable object the function returns to the variable x, then the second value to the variable y, and so on. There are only two values produced by this call to split, so x and y are both scalar values:
@assert x == "AA-BB"
@assert y == "CC"

Doing this a second time, like the OP does in the for loop, results in the same kind of output:
q, z = split(x, "-")
@assert q == "AA"
@assert z == "BB"

Notice that q and z are both scalars in this example. You may be confused because the value that is printed to the REPL when running the assignment line is this:
julia> q, z = split(x, "-")
2-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "AA"
 "BB"

However, that represents the raw output of the split method, not of either q or z from the assignment operation. The return value of an assignment operation is the right-hand side of the equals sign, not the left-hand side.
BoundsError
The error that the OP reports would result if breed were a Vector with length 1, but in the provided code, breed is a SubString{String}, meaning breed[2] should be a Char, like this example shows:
i = "ab-cd:ef"
x, y = split(i, ":")
q, z = split(x, "-")
@assert z == "cd"
@assert z[2] == 'd'

The following is an example of what the OP sees, which does not result from the example code provided by the OP, but is included here for reference:
julia> z_err = [z];
julia> z_err[2]
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Vector{SubString{String}} at index [2]
...


Aside: Why is the return value of the assignment operator the right-hand side and not the left-hand side? One reason is so that you can chain assignments of the output of the thing on the far right of the assignment chain without worrying about assignments that happen along the chain, like this:
a2, b2, c2 = a1, b1 = x = split("A,B,C", ",")
@assert x == ["A", "B", "C"]
@assert a1 == a2 == "A"
@assert b1 == b2 == "B"
@assert c2 == "C"

Note that c2 picks up the third value of the split method, even though there are only two variables assigned in the second assignment from the left.
